# Need two addition fields to be added in devise form used and saved in different table(invite table)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a sign up form using devise in ROR..i need to add nested form in this..but i am not able to add it..Can anyone help me to solve it please..
the below forms saves to user but i want it to add two fields which needs to be saved in invite table...

```
%h2 Sign up
= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|
  = devise_error_messages!

  .form-group
    %div
      = f.label :first_name, :class => "control-label"
      %br/
      = f.text_field :first_name, :autofocus => true, :class => "form-control narrow-control"
  .form-group
    %div
      = f.label :last_name, :class => "control-label"
      %br/
      = f.text_field :last_name, :class => "form-control narrow-control"
  .form-group
    %div
      = f.label :email, :class => "control-label"
      %br/
      = f.email_field :email, :class => "form-control narrow-control"
 %br/
  .form-group
    %div= f.submit "Sign up", :class => "btn btn-default"
```

I need below two fields(name,invite) to be added to the above form and need to add it to the table invite...

```
.form-group
    %div
      = f.label :name, "Your Name (Required)", :class => "control-label"
      %br/
      = f.text_field :name, :class => "form-control narrow-control"

  .form-group
    %div
      = f.label :invite, "Your invite (Required)", :class => "control-label"
      %br/
      = f.text_field :invite, :class => "form-control narrow-control"
```

Can Anyone help to get it fixed?

Comment: you need to use accepts_nested_attributes_for your invite model. see here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: And as you are using Devise you will also need to white list the attributes:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accept_nested attributes is the first step but since devise is handling the registrations you need to whitelist the attributes the controller will accept

I will suggest you use devise_parimeter_sanitizer in your application controller.

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
  u.permit(:first_name,:last_name,:email,  nested_attributes: [:name,:invite])
end
```

instead of nested you will need to specify the name of your model here.